# "concerning" those rights or interests

Tags: grammar

All,

I don't know how to use v.+ing in the normal sentence. Does there is any pattern for my study?

e.g.: This may be contrasted with the concept of "privity of contract" whereby only the original parties to the contract **concerning** those rights or interests would be bound.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're unclear on how to use v+ing, then this example is probably not the one to learn from. This is either upper-intermediate or advanced English.

Answer (score 0):

v+ing is used for (at least) three different, related things.  It can form the present continuous tense.  It forms gerunds (that function like noun phrases) and it forms participles (that function as modifiers)

In this case the phrase "concerning those rights and interests" is a modifier, that modifies and describes the type of contract.

"Concern" here means "is about".  The contract *is about* those rights or interests. Only the original parties to this type of contract would be bound.